# C++ Function call as a parameter, not working

Tags: c++

http://pastebin.com/CsViwQFg
I'm using an SDK known as DragonFireSDK and there's a function called TouchAdd() that let's me add a function as a parameter (in this case: MoveLeft() and MoveRight()).
The only problem is, if the function is in a class (in this case, the Player class), I get the following errors:

```
Player *player;

void AppMain()
{
    player = new Player(20,20,10);

    tleft = TouchAdd(0,0,180,480,player->MoveLeft,0);
    tright = TouchAdd(180,0,180,480,player->MoveRight,0);
}
```

The error:

```
error C3867: 'Player::MoveLeft': function call missing argument list; use '&Player::MoveLeft' to create a pointer to member
error C3867: 'Player::MoveRight': function call missing argument list; use '&Player::MoveRight' to create a pointer to member
```

Comment: You may find that you need to have static functions (depends on the interface definition I think)

Comment: What is the signature of the `TouchAdd` function? Eg., what type is the parameter for the function?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass function as a parameter then syntax is `&Player::MoveLeft;` as it is not bound to any object such as `player`.

Answer (score 2):

The DragonFireSDK appears to want a "C" callable function and you're trying to pass a member function (though not using the right syntax).  I think you'll need to do something like:

```
Player *player;

extern "C"
int PlayerMoveLeft(int id, int event, int x, int y)
{
    // do something - I'm not sure what might be possible 
    //  to get a pointer or a reference to the player object
    //  hopefully one or more parameters passed to this callback
    //  will have the information you need to do that

    // or if you only have one global player, you're set - 
    //  just use it
    Player* player = /* ??? */;

    player->MoveLeft( id, event, x, y); // or whatever needs to be passed

    return 0;
}

extern "C"
int PlayerMoveRight(int id, int event, int x, int y)
{
    Player* player = /* ??? */;

    player->MoveRight( id, event, x, y); // or whatever needs to be passed

    return 0;
}


void AppMain()
{
    player = new Player(20,20,10);

    tleft = TouchAdd(0,0,180,480,PlayerMoveLeft,0);
    tright = TouchAdd(180,0,180,480,PlayerMoveRight,0);
}
```

Note that even though a static member function will often work (since there's no 'hidden' `this` pointer passed in, strictly speaking you should use non-member `extern "C"` functions.

Comment: As someone mentioned in a now deleted comment, the `id` parameter might have enough information to find the targeted `Player` object - maybe by maintaining a map of these DragonFire ID's to `Player` objects.  I don't know enough about the DragonFireSDK to do more than speculate on that.

Answer (score 1):

Since the function signature of `TouchAdd` (taken from [here](http://www.dragonfiresdk.net/help/DragonFireSDKHelp.html?touchadd.htm)) is

```
int TouchAdd(int x, int y, int width, int height, int (*callback)(int id, int event, int x, int y), int id);
```

the expected function must be a *free* function, eg:

```
int myCallback(int id, int event, int x, int y){
  // do your stuff
}

void AppMain(){
  tLeft = TouchAdd(....,&myCallback,...);
}
```

You can't pass a member function pointer (`&Player::MoveX`), since that function needs to be called on an object of that class (`Player`). So you need to use a work-around for that:

```
Player* player;

int PlayerMoveLeft(int id, int event, int x, int y){
  return player->MoveLeft(id,event,x,y);
}

int PlayerMoveRight(int id, int event, int x, int y){
  return player->MoveRight(id,event,x,y);
}

void AppMain(){
  player = new Player(20,20,10);
  tLeft = TouchAdd(...,&PlayerMoveLeft,...);
  tRight = TouchAdd(...,&PlayerMoveRight,...);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `id` is the custom parameter that gets passed to the callback. If you only have 32-bit targets (and it seems like DragonFireSDK is meant only for iPhone, so I guess the answer is yes), you can cast it to Player* to bind to the player instance.

```
int PlayerMoveLeft(int id, int event, int x, int y)
{
    Player* player = reinterpret_cast<Player*>(id);

    return player->MoveLeft(event, x, y);
}

int PlayerMoveRight(int id, int event, int x, int y)
{
    Player* player = (Player*)id;

    return player->MoveRight(event, x, y);
}

void AppMain()
{
    Player* player = new Player(20,20,10);

    tleft = TouchAdd(0,0,180,480,PlayerMoveLeft,(int)player);
    tright = TouchAdd(180,0,180,480,PlayerMoveRight,(int)player);
}
```

Even if that doesn't work, or you don't want to use kinda-ugly type casts, you can always have a global or static object with lookup tables. Making PlayerMoveLeft and PlayerMoveRight static members of the Player class may also look nicer, and I think it should play well with TouchAdd().

Answer (score 0):

```
tleft = TouchAdd(0,0,180,480,player->MoveLeft,0);
tright = TouchAdd(180,0,180,480,player->MoveRight,0);
```

You're not passsing arguments to `MoveLeft` and `MoveRight` functions. I suppose they're function call as the title of your topic says, so you must pass arguments as well IF they take arguments.

If they're don't take argument, then do this:

```
tleft = TouchAdd(0,0,180,480,player->MoveLeft(),0);
tright = TouchAdd(180,0,180,480,player->MoveRight(),0);
```

---

If they're NOT function calls, instead you want to pass the member function pointers, then do this:

```
tleft = TouchAdd(0,0,180,480, &Player::MoveLeft,0);
tright = TouchAdd(180,0,180,480, &Player::MoveRight,0);
```

You also need to pass the instance so that member functions can be invoked later on.

It would be better if you let us know the signature of `TouchAdd` function. So that we can answer more specifically.

Comment: I believe the OP is trying to pass a function pointer, not invoke the function and pass the return value from the function.

Comment: @forsvarir: Maybe. That is why I added that also to my post.

Comment: @Downvoter: Please specify the reason. Only downvote doesn't help me correct myself.

Comment: I imagine it's because the first half of your answer seems unrelated to the question.   It's entirely possible they downvoted without seeing the second bit that you added, one of the risks of posting before you're finished.

Comment: @forsvarir: The question is not clear enough. I didn't assume. I answered it from all possible angles. Also, even if I posted the first part only, the downvote doesn't make sense, since the question is not clear as to what exactly he wants. In fact, first part makes sense seeing the title of the topic : `C++ Function call as a parameter`.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, so I can't tell you for sure, I'm just telling you that my impression from your original answer was that you hadn't read the question and it's possible that somebody else may have had a similar feeling...  You asked for feed back as to why it happened, I've just offered a suggestion... Largely, you can take it or leave it :)